# Floating Action Button does not raise OnClick event

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have the Following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/rlMap">
    <org.mapsforge.map.android.view.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/windArrow"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fab" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/settings"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the following code in the OnCreate method:

```
...
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG,"FAB Setting Clicked");
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppPreferences.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
...
```

But when I press the button nothing happens, The intent does not run, and the log is not written.

The button animation **is** working and every time I press the button the following log message appears :

> D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

So there seems to be some reaction.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you setting the click listener? Inside an `Activity` or `Fragment`? Can you verify the listener is being set to the button? You can debug or print a log before/after `fab.setOnClickListener`

Comment: The listener is being set inside a class which eventually derives from Activity. The listener is being set, I checked using a Log debug of fab.hasOnClickListeners() before and after.

Comment: You can add a click event inside the xml e.g -- (android:onClick="runThis") -- and then in the Activity add -- (public void runThis(View v) { .....  }) .Try this way and see if it works

Comment: @Tasos it worked! My question is why?

Comment: I have no idea. maybe its where you placed your listener. Try inside the onCreate -- if you do have it inside onCreate try outside

Comment: Facing the same problem, setting the OnClickListener in the OnCreateView method of the MainActivityFragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution suggested by @Tasos worked:

add a click event inside the xml e.g

```
android:onClick="runThis"
```

and then in the Activity add

```
public void runThis(View v) { ..... }
```

Comment: Same problem here, I'm also interested in why it is not working.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
fab.bringToFront();
```

Should help.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem when I failed to return the View object, but instead made another call to infalter.inflate like this:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
/* setup onClick handler */
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

The fix was replacing the return with

```
return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the following solution to deal with lost clicks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener 
{
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(LOG_HEADER,"onClick");       
        }
}

public class SearchFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout )inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        ll.setOnClickListener((MainActivity)getActivity());
        return ll;
    }
}
```