# Android FloatingActionButton "onclick" does not work

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclick, floating-action-button

I'm new to AndroidStudio and Java. I tried to use a FloatingActionButton to open another activity in my App but it does not work.. Here is the code of the Button in the XML file (the button itself works, I just have problems to link it correctly to the other activity):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/FAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:onClick="openInputWindow"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_36dp"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Code in the Java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void openInputWindow (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddElementActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: So what is not happening? Let me see your manifest file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating Action Button does not raise OnClick event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189833/floating-action-button-does-not-raise-onclick-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said the button works but just does not redirect to the activity. This implies that your activity cannot be found (Check your logcat)

Make sure the activity you want to navigate to is listed in the Manifest.xml (it's not important to add an intent filter)

```
<activity android:name=".AddElementActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: in this case, he would have a line in log, 
`did you define this activity in your manifest.xml`

Comment: Thanks mate, I just had to added to the manifest.xml file and now it works!

Comment: You were saying ibrahim?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how your complete xml looks like.

But FloatingActionButton in the layout xml should be placed at the top to get touch events.

Comment: That's not true at all... why do you think that?